# What would've happened if we used Europa's water to integrate into Mars atmosphere?

Tags: planets, terraforming

Lets assume we as humankind can, not only wormhole the spacecraft, but planets and moons. So, what would've happened to Mars if we pulled icy Europa closer to the sun, we might use our flaming star to melt it down. If we at first, travel it through portal like structures next to Venus. We can heat it up, so it melts faster for calculated time and then send it back towards Mars. There we will pull Europa into orbit around our red brother and gradually siphon off some reasonable amount of water onto Mars' surface. So there'll be 30-50% of firm ground to use for colonization. What is needed after such task has been done for sufficient amount of oxygen to sustain life? Or before that?

PS: bare in mind, if Europa contains organic life, we might not use it, but Iapetus,Rhea,Enceladus,Tethys and/or Dione.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Customary to explain why.

Comment: are you asking about what happens if we add water to Mars or are you asking what happens if we add the amount of water on Europa to Mars?  I ask because Europa's oceans have more water than the Earth's.  I'm confident it would submerge most of Mars.

Comment: Reasonable amount of water off course. If I intend on breathing there that means I want some land to be habitable, perhaps Olympus Mons and other tall spots of planet will do in. As for down voting if I'll paraphrase your remark, would you make you vote go away? Thank you for your answers by the way, many people around the net gave lots of different assumptions. Now I want to explore some extra routes of this speculating tale.

Comment: Why the hand-waving about wormholes &c?  It'd be perfectly feasible (though expensive) to do it by launching chunks of ice with mass drivers.  All you'd need is working fusion power plants.

Comment: How can this question be too broad ? It is basicly: What happens if we take X planet and adds Y Ice and Z energy where X = Mars, Y = Europa, Z = Sun. Looks pretty narrow to me.

Comment: @Jim2B it's not customary to explain down votes. Courteous, perhaps, but it's not required.

Comment: This question takes over-complicating simple matters to a different level…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're moving gigatons of material all over the the solar system, let's steal some other materials instead of just water. (I'm handwaving on the quantities of the materials needs.  I'm assuming that the various donors have sufficient quantities to avoid huge changes to the donor.) "Thefts" are described in an order designed for maximum benefit.

Injecting Iron/Nickel (for magnetic field) and uranium (for heating) into Mars' core would get us a workable magnetosphere.  This should cut down the amount of atmospheric stripping from the solar wind and would make Mars more conducive to walking around outside without a spacesuit.  Perhaps this could come from asteroids (not sure if there's enough iron/nickel in the solar system to make that happen).  This would also increase the surface gravity on Mars and lots and lots of earthquakes as Mars adjusts to it's new core.  Please answer all of your "What was Mars like 2 billion years ago" questions before starting core injection.

Stealing some CO2 from Venus to seed Mars' atmosphere has a two fold benefit.  Venus becomes slightly less hellish and Mars gets a nice warm blanket.

Water transfer from Europa starts here when surface temperatures are above freezing in most places.  Start seeding single cell life forms here.

Jupiter has huge amounts of ammonia and ammonium sulfide in its atmosphere which are lovely sources of nitrogen.  I'm not chemist so I can't say how to go about freeing up that nitrogen for use by plants.

Since we are unceremoniously injecting the materials we want into the Mars environment, terraforming would take much much less time than if we were doing it the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 2):

Europa is thought to have more water than Earth, so terraformers will have plenty to work with.

Mars really does not need that much water to establish a functioning hydrological cycle, if you were to inundate Mars like that you would have a water planet (and unless you were doing other things to add heat, it would rapidly freeze over. Unlike Europa, there is no gravitational kneading to keep the ocean liquid under the ice, so the planet would be covered in a glacier many kilometers thick. Since the Lithosphere of Mars is locked in place and the core is cold, there would be earthquakes as the crust adjusted to the extra weight, but not extreme earthquakes (mostly a continual series of tremors).

Using "just enough" water would provide the classical picture of a terraformed Mars, with most of the northern hemisphere covered by the Boreal Sea, and the southern hemisphere covered in thousands of crater lakes. The Martian ecosystem will still need some sort of external heat source for the water to remain liquid (platoons of orbiting mirrors is the most common idea), and with proper design could remain viable for eons.

Probably the more interesting idea, if you are shuffling Europa around, is to use some of the remaining water from Europa to rehydrate Venus (although there are some steps you might want to do before the "add water" phase). Even after that, there should still be one ocean's worth of water left on Europa, although given the small size would either escape, or if put back in Jupiter's orbit, freeze over again.